# What does ._ mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I find a point:

```
var example = /1/._ ;
```

It can be accept by the interpreter of chrome or Firefox ,and it always return `undefined`.

But I don't understand why, is `._` a special usage in regular expression？ Or is there something else I don't know?

I have searched in Google, but get nothing.

Answer (score 12):

`_` [is a valid name for a property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6) :

> **IdentifierStart ::**
>
> UnicodeLetter
>
> $
>
> _
>
> \ UnicodeEscapeSequence

As there is no property with this name, you just get `undefined`. There's nothing specific to regular expression here : there's rarely a property with this name unless you define it or import [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) (then it's not on regexes, just on `window`).

You would have get the same result with

```
var example = /1/.abracadabra;
```

or

```
var example = ({}).π;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down:

```
var example = /1/            .                                                 _;
              ^ regex object ^ dot (meaning, accessing a method of a property) ^ attempt to access a property named "_".
```

Since `_` is a property that doesn't exist, you'll get `undefined` every time.

Much like you would with

```
var example = document.somethingThatDoesntExist;
```